# Как передать изображение из canvas по ftp

Tags: php, html5, canvas

Есть скрипт создающий изображение в canvas, это изображение получается сохранить в папку, а вот передать его по ftp не удается, он создает файл но явно с ошибками.

1 код сохранения в папку выглядит так

```
    $img = $_POST['dataURL'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    if($data == false) {
        echo 'docede fail';
    } else {
        $file = mktime() . ".png";
        $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    }
```

2 Код передачи файла по ftp

```
$ftp_server = '*******';
$ftp_user_name = '*******';
$ftp_user_pass = '*******';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 9021);
// входим при помощи логина и пароля
$file = mktime() . ".png";
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$file_data = $_POST['dataURL'];
//$file_data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $file_data);
//$file_data = str_replace(' ', '+', $file_data);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $file,  $file_data, FTP_BINARY);

if (!$upload) {
      echo "Ошибка загрузки файла";
   }


    echo 'done';
}
```

Я понимаю что во 2 варианте нужно как то декодировать его, вопрос как?

Comment: 3 строка первого куска вероятно ломает изображение

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ftp-put.php прочитайте внимательно документацию

Comment: это разный код! 1 работает, не работает второй